# how to read RFID card from Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, web, asp.net-web-api

so im doing a side project, and i want to use Angular with asp.net REST api connecting to a mssql server.

the project is basically a site that could be placed in a company/school canteen, with a touch screen, and an rfid scanner for employee cards.

i've got no issues with the angular / api part. but how would i go about reading events from a rfid scanner from angular? is this even possible?

the usecase is that i want to scan the employee card, then in the angular client app, prompt if the user is correct "Welcome, are you "firstname" "Lastname"? (confirmbutton)"
then use the gathered employee informations later in this process when the employee checksout from the canteen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scenario 1: Server and RFID reader are on the same device

Example:

You have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS and .NET 5 on it. You buy a RFID reader [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KGBJ9VG), and you either find a library for it ([like this one](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/tree/main/src/devices/Mfrc522)) or you start reading the datasheet and write your own library with .NET [I2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.i2c?view=iot-dotnet-1.3) or [SPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.spi?view=iot-dotnet-1.3) APIs. Then your ASP.NET Core website on the Pi will listen for RFID events (maybe with a background worker or maybe another .NET app will notify it with gRPC or API) and notifies the client (Angular in you case) with WebSocket or polling or some other method.

### Scenario 2: One server with many web clients on other locations

Example:

You have an ASP.NET Core API that doesn't know anything about RFID and just works with normal data like any Web API. You then tell your clients to buy a USB RFID ([like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B7H6CQ2)) and you use [Web USB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB) inside your Angular app to communicate with the RFID device (I don't know how) and then call necessary APIs on the ASP.NET server. ([BBC micro:bit](https://microbit.org/) uses this method, they connect to their devices via Web USB)

Example 2 (this is probably the easiest way):

Write an Android app with Ionic that uses the [NFC plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc) to communicate with NFC tags and call any API you want. You can then run it under [kiosk mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices). All your clients need then is a cheap android device.

Note: You can combine these scenarios, for example in scenario 1 you can still call a centralized API.

Comment: Sorry for the late marked answer, this did though point me in the right direction, i ended up going a whole other way, but the scenario 2 was working fine for me with a USB RFID. thanks alot

Comment: what did you end up doing? and how did you set up angular to work with USB RFID?